# Writing to text file using geometry tokens of ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, geometry

I am trying to write into a text file using geometry tokens but they're not being called upon.

```
 open(infile, "w")
 cursor = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass(fc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@", "NAME"])
  ID = 0
  for row in cursor:
      f = open("rivers_IWM.txt", "w")
      f.write(str("OID@"))
      f.write(str("SHAPE@X"))
      f.write(str("SHAPE@Y"))
```

Comment: Which ArcGIS version do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it in the following format:

```
import arcpy,os

from arcpy import env
ws = env.workspace = (r"F:\Ahmad\Test\PT") # Change the working directory

fc = "Cities.shp" # Change the shapefile

fld_list = ["OID@","SHAPE@x","SHAPE@y","Name"]
with open(os.path.join(ws,"cities.txt"),"w") as text_file:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fld_list) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            write_text = "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
            text_file.write(write_text + "\n")
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like every time you pass a row in your cursor you are creating a new text file.  You are basically re-writing the text file for each row.  You also need to close you text file at the end of (and outside of) your for loop.